# How does the speed of a script influence polling frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor, frequency

I don't fully understand how the frequency of a script running on a MCU influences measurements of a sensor via polling. For example:

I have an ADXL345 chip, and in my (Arduino) code I've set the datarate of the chip to be 400 Hz. This means it should be producing 400 measurements every second.

Now the Arduino script I am writing runs at a certain speed as well (on the MCU), and therefore the function that 'polls' the ADXL345 is called with the frequency at which the 'main' MCU script runs. If I add a while loop, I can regulate the frequency of the main script and put it at e.g. 400 Hz (or alternatively I can add a timer for the individual function to be called at certain time intervals).

However, what happens if the frequency of the script is lower or higher than the datarate I have selected for the ADXL345 data output rate? If the script frequency is lower, are some ADXL 345 measurements destroyed or is there a delay? And if the script frequency is higher, will some of the measurements be duplicated (to fill in the missing gaps?) And is there a good way to go about this, to regulate the polling frequency in an optimal way?

I guess this question is independent of which protocol I use, but for further clarity it's SPI.

Does anyone know the answer or could point me to some good explanation/literature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason that manufacturers publish [datasheets](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) for the parts they make.

All of your answers are in there.

A short summary:

1. If you don't read the data fast enough, samples will be lost.
2. There's a 32 sample buffer so that you don't have to immediately read every sample.
3. The chip can provide an interrupt output so that you know when it has data for you.
4. If you prefer to poll (or must poll,) there's bit in at least one message that tells you when there's new data available.  If you poll faster than the chip acquires data, then that bit tells you when you can get new samples.

Using all or any of those abilities may require additional setup (commands sent over the bus to setup FIFO, or an additional connection from the chip to your processor for an interrupt.)  All of that is in the datasheet.  Sometimes there's a **lot** stuff to know, and there'll be programming notes or application notes in addition to the datasheet.  Often times, the datasheets will include a reference to such additional information. Other times you'll have to go searching for it.

Comment: Regarding point 4: well it's not that I particularly want to poll or anything, it's just that the [sparkfun ADXL345 library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_ADXL345_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/SparkFun_ADXL345.cpp) I am using seems to do it that way. And I had the impression that for reading out sensors at regular intervals polling is the more standard way to do things? (n.b. I have a background in mechanical engineering and am not very experienced in this topic)

Comment: Polling is not especially good for reading things at a regular interval.  The timers in the hardware are better for that.  Your polling loop can be interrupted by interrupts.  That's why you use interrupts - to break into slow running, uncritical stuff and carry out a high priority task that has to be handled right **now.**  The most reliable way to read the data would be to let the chip store data in its own buffer, then give you an interrupt when you need to read the buffer.  The measurements are all precisely timed, and you won't drop any.

Comment: Polling is more or less standard in Arduino (and similar) projects because it is simpler to implement, not because it is better.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Sparkfun library supports interrupts.  It certainly has methods for setting up the interrupt pins on the chip.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I actually [found application notes](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1025.pdf) explaining the FIFO memory management system for ADXL345. And I came across a [github ADXL345 arduino library](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/ADXL345) that has implemented the necessary FIFO functions

Comment: Also, how would you go about this when using two or more ADXL sensors? How can I synchronise the data from the two accelerometers? Because now the measurement values are transferred in batches. (N.B. I am using two accelerometers to increase the accuracy of my readings).